Trying to to copy values from a variable range and use that range to determine number of rows to add to table
My experience with VBA is extremely limited. I have data in Sheet called "Daily Dashboard" from M19:T39. These need to be copied as entries on a table called "ReportingLog" on sheet called "Reporting Tool" daily for a historical record. The number of rows to copy is variable. So I need help with code to determine how many rows there are, add those to the table, then copy the data. Below is what i've come up with so far, This was pretty easy when I was only copying one row but now I'm stuck. I placed question marks where I'm having issues.
Sub Dispatch_Report_Save()

'Confirm with user

    If MsgBox("WARNING: Continuing will add a new date entry to the Dispatch Report Log and should only be used once per day. Update Button should be used to make changes once already saved. Would you like to continue? ", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    
    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Dashboard")
    Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Reporting Tool")
    
'Set active worksheet
    Worksheets("Reporting Tool").Activate
    
'Add new Rows to Tables
    Set newrow = Sheets("Reporting Tool").ListObjects("ReportingLog").ListRows.Add(?????????)

'Copy values
    sh2.Range("?????????").Select
    Selection.Copy
    sh2.Range("?????????").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'Set active worksheet
    Worksheets("Daily Dashboard").Activate
    
'Select Cell
    sh1.Range("E6").Select
    
'Success Message
    MsgBox "Daily Dispatch Statistics have been saved."

End Sub


Pls share the layout of sheet "Reporting Tool" and "Daily Dashboard".

I can't share the actual sheet becuase there are company financials. I created a dummy in sheets so you could understand the layout https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zfNqQ_xOE3qycbbXWUIrob4YPq5ABNzFxWD-1wruMv4/edit?usp=sharing


Don't need to use Select in most cases.

How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA
Microsoft documentation:

Range.End property (Excel)


Range.Offset property (Excel)


Range.Resize property (Excel)


Option 1:
Sub Dispatch_Report_Save()
    'Confirm with user
    If MsgBox("WARNING: Continuing will add a new date entry to the Dispatch Report Log and should only be used once per day. Update Button should be used to make changes once already saved. Would you like to continue? ", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Dashboard")
    Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Reporting Tool")
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srcRng As Range, RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Set srcRng = sh1.Range("M19:T" & lastRow)
    RowCnt = srcRng.Rows.Count
    ColCnt = srcRng.Columns.Count
    Dim rCol As Range
    With Sheets("Reporting Tool").ListObjects("ReportingLog")
        Set rCol = .Range.Columns(1).Cells(.Range.Columns(1).Cells.Count + 1).Resize(RowCnt, 1)
        rCol.Value = Date ' Col date
        rCol.Offset(, 1).Value = srcRng.Columns(1).Value ' Col Job
        rCol.Offset(, 2).Resize(, ColCnt - 2).Value = srcRng.Columns(4).Resize(, ColCnt - 2).Value ' Other Cols
        .Resize sh2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion ' expand table
    End With
    'Success Message
    MsgBox "Daily Dispatch Statistics have been saved."
End Sub


Option 2:

Load data into array and write output to sheet all at once.

Option Explicit
Sub Dispatch_Report_Save2()
    'Confirm with user
    If MsgBox("WARNING: Continuing will add a new date entry to the Dispatch Report Log and should only be used once per day. Update Button should be used to make changes once already saved. Would you like to continue? ", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Dashboard")
    Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Reporting Tool")
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srcRng As Range, RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Set srcRng = sh1.Range("M19:T" & lastRow)
    RowCnt = srcRng.Rows.Count
    ColCnt = srcRng.Columns.Count
    Dim arrData, i As Long, j As Long, iCol As Long
    arrData = srcRng
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        arrData(i, 2) = arrData(i, 1)
        arrData(i, 1) = Date
        For j = 3 To UBound(arrData, 2) - 1
            arrData(i, j) = arrData(i, j + 1)
        Next
    Next
    Dim rCell As Range
    With Sheets("Reporting Tool").ListObjects("ReportingLog")
        Set rCell = .Range.Columns(1).Cells(.Range.Columns(1).Cells.Count + 1)
        rCell.Resize(RowCnt, ColCnt - 1).Value = arrData
        .Resize sh2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion ' expand table
    End With
    'Success Message
    MsgBox "Daily Dispatch Statistics have been saved."
End Sub

